# Spotify login in spotify iOS sdk beta release version 3

Tags: spotify

I have spotify demo downloaded from github.com beta release- version 3.  On login it is redirecting to safari login page of spotify after login it is not returning back to application. On second run of the application and login it will open account.spotify.com and gives error INVALID_CLIENT: Invalid redirect URL

Answer (score 2):

I realise this post is a little old, however are you still have trouble?

The INVALID_CLIENT response will be a programatic/setup error. Ensure that your Redirect URI is correctly set (should be **my-app-name**://callback) in the My Applications section of developer.spotify.com.

Secondly, ensure you have done the following in Xcode.

1) Under Targets->Info->URL Types->Click the plus sign, put in an Identifier (can be anything) and then URL Schemes should be "**my-app-name**" (as above).

2)Under Targets->Build Settings->Linking-> Ensure "-ObjC" is added under "Other Linker Flags".

Then it should work perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a set of client credentials on the Spotify developer website, then set up your token exchange service and input those credentials into your project.

I suggest following the [Spotify iOS SDK Tutorial](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/spotify-ios-sdk/tutorial/) for a step-by-step guide.

Comment: Thanks for your reponse. I have followed the same steps before posting on stackoverflow still not working.

Comment: The `Invalid redirect URL` message suggests you've not created a redirect URL on developer.spotify.com or added it correctly to the Xcode project. Delete your project and (carefully) follow the tutorial again - you missed some steps.